# Open Powershell as Administrator at Current File Explorer Directory Keyboard Shortcut (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, autohotkey, administrator

Let's say that I'm browsing through Windows File Explorer, and suddenly I decide that I would like to open Powershell as administrator at the current directory (the directory that I'm at in File Explorer).  Naturally, I'd like to open this as quickly as possible, so a keyboard shortcut to do this would be desirable.

I presume that this may only be possible to do with AutoHotKey, which I am open to using if necessary. **Any way** to create a keyboard shortcut to do this is what I want.  So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do this with the native method by simply clicking in the folder you wish to open **Powershell** as administrator from **File Explorer**, and then press <kbd>**`Alt`**</kbd><kbd>**`F`**</kbd><kbd>**`S`**</kbd><kbd>**`A`**</kbd> one key right after the other.

- German version: <kbd>**`Alt`**</kbd><kbd>**`D`**</kbd><kbd>**`S`**</kbd><kbd>**`A`**</kbd>

> 1. Click in or on the folder which you want to open as administrator
>      from **PowerShell**
>
>    [image]
> 2. Press <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> then <kbd>**F**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 3. Press <kbd>**S**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 4. Press <kbd>**A**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 5. Now **PowerShell** will open as administrator in that folder as requested.
>
>    [image]

Comment: These drawings are completely wrong. 1) They're not red. 2) They're not freehand. 3) They're not circles.

Comment: @SombreroChicken 3) They are circles *with corners*. 2) Poster may have had a steady hand due to lack of alcohol. 1) [It's not easy being green](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRZ-IxZ46ng).

Comment: According to Pimp Juice IT Answer, here the german version: **ALT** -> **D** -> **S** -> **A**

Comment: I just discovered that you can also add this button as a shortcut to your folder! Right click on the "Open as Admin" and select "Add to Quick Access Toolbar". Now Admin Powershell is a permanent part of my Explorer's top bar :)

Answer (score 3):

Shift click while inside the folder and click 'Open PowerShell window here'

[image: GIF]

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but seeing the other response, this seems a lot easier...

Comment: Question asked about opening as administrator, which doesn't happen here, right?

Comment: @palsch It depends whether you're lo̶g̶g̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶r̶o̶o̶t̶ using an admin `%SHELL%`. But almost certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean setting a keyboard shortcut to open the Powershell?
For example, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to open the PowerShell ISE

To do this, go to the Powershell shortcut in the start menu>>Right-click, select open containing folder>>Right-click on Powershell and select properties.
On the 'Shortcut' tab, there is a selection labeled **Shortcut**[none] click the box then press the key combination that you wish to use.
Apply the changes and click OK