# Keyboard shortcut to open PowerShell from the Desktop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

I know there is a keyboard shortcut to run PowerShell from the File Explorer as explained here: [Open Powershell as Administrator at Current File Explorer Directory Keyboard Shortcut (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1309679/open-powershell-as-administrator-at-current-file-explorer-directory-keyboard-sho)

But can I open PowerShell while I am on the Desktop? Something like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open a File Explorer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, you may see little underlines under the options. If you press <kbd>I</kbd>, PowerShell will open.

So, the shortcut is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> for an elevated prompt).

[image: Win+X menu]

Comment: For me the command prompt is on the place of PowerShell.

Comment: @user598527 that is a taskbar setting (right click the taskbar->taskbar settings->"Replace Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell..."

Answer (score 26):

You can pin your PowerShell to your taskbar and then move the icon to the far left.

Now you can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to start it.

for an elevated PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: nice. and then you can lock your taskbar to avoid accidental shifts

Comment: To expand on @Peter Hahndorf approach. 

You can pin it anywhere on the task bar between the 0-9 pinned position and use whatever number corresponds to where you have it pinned or you can just directly assign it a hot key combination in the shortcut properties settings.

Comment: To add to the answer, in case you already have a PowerShell window open and want to open a new one, the `Win`+`Shift`+`1` should help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set PowerShell to open up with any keyboard shortcut you want by simply right clicking on any PowerShell **shortcut** file then going to 'properties', then click in the "shortcut key" box and enter your key. I'll demonstrate below (In this case I'll be using Ctrl + Alt + T)

[image: Demo]

Comment: Note: The shortcut itself must be on the desktop and nowhere else for this to work